Android Studio Property error- typeerror: cannot read property 'sdkDebugLogsLevelVerbose' of null, js engine
TypeError: cannot read property 'sdkDebugLogsLevelVerbose' of null, js engine.
This is the error I am getting when I try to reinstall and build the same project on another machine. Although my app is working fine on my current machine. I have the same version and all the packages installed in the build can someone help me solve this issue.
